# The verbs "sift" and "sieve"

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

After washing rice in water I separate the rice from the water using a sieve.

How to describe the action of separating using the verb "sift" or "sieve"?

Maybe:

- I sift rice out of water.
- I sift rice out from water.
- I sift out water from rice.

What about the verb "sieve"? How to use it in this situation?

Comment: In British English, we call this [straining](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strain) the rice.

Comment: In American English one would also use "strain", or maybe "drain"

Answer (score 5):

In the case of your specific example, neither. Although a 'sieve' may be used, when separating water from a cooked product like rice, or boiled vegetables, most people would say either *draining* or *straining*.

'Sieving' and 'sifting' are normally just for dry items, and mostly interchangeable. 'Sieving' means putting anything through a sieve, and there are at least two reasons you might do that. It could be used to *separate* larger, coarser grains from the finer ones for purification, and some product might be discarded. Another reason is to make a product such as flour *finer* by forcing it through a sieve. In this latter process, nothing is left over, there is no 'separation'.

'Sifting' has a wider use and can mean various kinds of sorting or separation processes - for example, my employer uses the term 'sifting' for separating suitable job applications from ones to be rejected. However, the term is still used for either process of putting something through a kitchen sieve, even when there is no separation intended.

Comment: All true. One other clarification -- sifting is only for dry ingredients, but sieving can be done with liquid. One sifts flour, for instance, but doesn't sieve it. The nominalizations are different, too. One uses a _sifter_ to sift flour, but a _sieve_ to sieve with. Sieves are also often used to drain liquids from cooked foods, but never sifters, which are designed to be used only with flour or other granular materials within a narrow range of granularity.